# Angular $scope function not working outside of ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope

I have a `<table>` element, at which I declared a controller (only one in the app at the moment). I also have a `ng-repeat` on `<tr>` in the `<tbody>` element, which is working just fine, creating multiple table rows as intended. In the controller i have some api calls which are called for single table rows and which work just fine, and a function called from one of the `<th>`'s in `<thead>`, which I can't get to work. I know it's a scope thing, but I just can't grasp what I'm doing wrong.

To sum it up:

**simplified html fragment:**

```
<table ng-controller='myController'>
    <thead>
         <tr>
             <th>Username</th>
             <th><button ng-click='doStuff()'>Do stuff</button></th>
         </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
         <tr ng-repeat='user in users'>
             <td>{{user.name}}</td>
             <td><button ng-click='delete(user)'>Delete</button>
         </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**simplified js fragment:**

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$http', users, function($scope, $http, users) {
    //api call to get users, working fine
    users.getAll().success(function(data) {
        $scope.users = data;
    });

    //api call to delete users, also working fine
    $scope.delete = function(user) {
        users.delete(user).success(function() {});
    };

    //can't get this to fire
    $scope.doStuff = function() {
        alert('I do stuff');
    };
}]);
```

Any insight would be helpful, thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

I assume the issue is comming from one of the modules, so I copied the whole thing into a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/vCrNWwo2TQMZOobElLlX?p=preview). Sorry for the styling, removed it for more code simplicity.

**EDIT 2**

After studying the plnkr I came to see that it was an unclosed `<div>` element in the `<thead>`. Ouch. Thanks for the replies, and please excuse my carelessness.

**EDIT 3**

An even more carefull study revealed, that the problem has in fact been also lying in poorly designed jasmine unit tests.

Comment: The code you posted is fine (except that `users` should be in quotes). `doStuff()` will be called when the button is clicked. I would try to reproduce your issue in a jsFiddle

Comment: Please check the updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be firing. I've had to simulate the asynchronous loading of `users`, but that shouldn't make a difference. Can you add a snippet to demonstrate the issue?

```js
 angular.module('app', []).controller('myController', ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout',
   function($scope, $http, $timeout) {
     //api call to get users, working fine

     $timeout(function() {
       $scope.users = [{
         name: 'A'
       }, {
         name: 'B'
       }];
     }, 1000);

     //api call to delete users, also working fine
     $scope.delete = function(user) {
       console.log('delete', user);
     };


     $scope.doStuff = function() {
       console.log('I do stuff');
     };
   }
 ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">

  <table ng-controller='myController'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>
          <button ng-click='doStuff()'>Do stuff</button>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat='user in users'>
        <td>{{user.name}}</td>
        <td>
          <button ng-click='delete(user)'>Delete</button>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```